# Reference multiple cells in multiple columns and return "text1" or "blank" if conditions met

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

In this example, the goal is to have three separate drop-down fields in Field1, Field2, and Field3. Each of these fields will reference data contained in the lower right-hand corner of the spreadsheet, ie: abc, def, geh, or fij in Field1. The goal is to have Field4 (D1) reference the data the user selects from the drop-down fields A2, B2, and C2, and return referenced text from Field4 (L18-L22) in the D2 cell.

In this scenario, I've achieved this result using an IF formula, but I was wondering if there is a simpler syntax available to achieve this result.

Comment: Did either of the answers below work for you? If so please mark  one as correct. It is something only the person posing the question can do. Click on the green check mark by the one that is correct, the one you used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this array formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($L$19:$L$22,MATCH(1,IF(($I$19:$I$22 = A2)*($J$19:$J$22 = B2)*($K$19:$K$22 = C2),1,0),0)),"")
```

It is an array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  Put in D2 and confirm with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  Then Copy down the desired rows.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) for a quick three column match.

In D2 as,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(L$19:L$22, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:$4)/((I$19:I$22=A2)*(J$19:J$22=B2)*(K$19:K$22=C2)), 1)), "")
```

Fill down as necessary. The [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) takes care of non-matches.

[image: aggregate_three_column_match]